# How to make Polyline draw WPF c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to wpf, I have a task where I need to draw a real time graph with an array of numbers that changes once per second or less. I searched a lot of solutions and the best for me chose to use standard graphics, namely the "Polyline" element as a binding using "PointCollection" that I can calculate in a separate method. The code below doesn't work and I don't understand how to make it work. The ultimate goal is to make the same graph as in windows 10 task manager

This is the Polyline code with a link to the property

```
<Polyline Name="Graph"
          StrokeLineJoin="Round"       
          Stroke="Red"
          Points="{Binding Points}">
</Polyline>
```

Here I'm trying to implement an MVVM pattern and to test the code I assign random coordinate values, then I'll do their normal calculation, but this solution doesn't work and I don't understand what I need to do to have my graph drawn in a new thread in real time like in the task manager

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        PointCollection _Points;
        public PointCollection Points
        {
            get { return _Points; }
            set
            {
                _Points = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Points);
            }
        }

        void DrawGraph()
        {
            Points = new PointCollection();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();

                double y;

                for (double x = 0; x < 490; x = x + 2)
                {
                    y = rnd.Next(0, 235);

                    Points.Add(new Point(x, y));

                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                }

            });
        }
    }
```